# php to write a file as root user

Tags: php, shell

I have my script running on plesk latest version and plesk does not have write permissions. I have to write a configuration file with the values from database.

I tried the following,

```
$pathconn =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mysite/_conn.php";
if(file_exists($pathconn)){
    chmod($pathconn, 0777);
}
$file_contents = file_get_contents($pathconn);
$file_contents = str_replace("webuser_admin", $username."_admin", $file_contents);
$file_contents = str_replace("webpass", $mysql_password, $file_contents);
$file_contents = str_replace("web_db", $username."_ss", $file_contents);
file_put_contents($pathconn, $file_contents);
```

The php variables are coming from database and I need to update `_conn.php` file with those variables to run the website. I cannot do that because of permission issue.

Is there any other way to do that? I read somewhere that we can do that as a `apache` or `root` user. But I am not sure what does that mean. Help please..

Comment: I think this link maybe useful for your case
 
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35711/giving-php-permission-to-write-to-files-and-folders

Comment: I have no idea how to use those commands.

Comment: Are you stuck with Plesk? I haven't used it, but I have no problems writing to, or creating new files using Apache and cPanel, or my WAMP setup...

Comment: @Wade Shuler Actually I have most of the things working. But now I only need some php script which replaces some string from _conn.php with the values from databas. I am stuck here and have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://www.1hostingvision.com/shop/faq.cfm?Action=foundqa&faqid=976&FAQCategoryID=304

Comment: or create a perl or php file that does exactly, and only, what your needing.. and run that file from cron?

Comment: I can do this, but the requirement is this should be dynamic. I create the entire website using Plesk API and also create the database and user using the API. After that I need to place the database details in the `_conn.php` file which is again dynamic. So I cannot go in plesk and assign the permission manually every time.

Comment: Everytime a new vhosts is created for the new website which has the same files but the database values should be different to connect every website with its right database. So I store the values in a separate database and fetch the details from there and write the values replacing pre defined strings in `_conn.php` file.

Comment: According to requirement, these all process is done on a click of a button so no cron can be included.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the linux distribution that you installed in your VPS you will have to type different commands but those steps remain  the same :

1.you have to log in to your server with **SSH**

2.find the name of your  web server **username**

3.Give **permissions** to web server with (chmod, chown) for the directory where you want to write data